# SessionInvalid issue

Tags: struts2, servlet-filters

In my application i have written a session filter which is used to invalidate the session. now what is happening is when the  user is idle for sometime it is going to Login page which is correct but after login again its showing the session invalid page. what could be reason please help

Comment: why you doing it in filter? this should better be done in some of action class

Comment: when you are creating the session in filter?

Answer (score 0):

Set Session again after login. It will work try..